# Tool for creating resizable images

Tags: ios, photoshop, nine-patch

I'm working with a designer generated photoshop psd that contains various UI elements for an iOS app, and I'm slicing their backgrounds into smaller images and using resizableImageWithCapInsets for efficiency. There are a lot of them, and it's quite tedious work.

What I'm looking for is a tool that will help with this process, something like [Draw NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) that will take a .png file, and a list of cap insets, and then spit out a smaller .png.

Anyone heard of such a thing?

Comment: maybe you could [learn to Applescript Photoshop](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.08/ScriptingPhotoshop/index.html) or some other graphics tool on a Macintosh so you could automate the process somewhat for your specific purposes?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anything, so I wrote a simple tool. If anyone else has this problem, here ya go:

https://github.com/kcoop/CapInsetImageGenerator

Comment: perfect! just what i was looking for! however since @3x images came along i tried to use it without the retina option but by specifying pixels (not points) but i when i make an image that's capped 150 from left and 50 from right, the resulting image is 402 pixels wide.. do you know why this is happening? btw i could have paid for something like this, just saying..